# Why Grafana is not available for 32 bit windows machine

Tags: grafana

I couldn't find grafana for 32 bit windows machine in official website. please advice how can I install grafana

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link which guides *Building Grafana from source* since there is no exe file as such for 32 bit windows machines.
http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/